# Invalid input - URIString in webMethods 8 using AS2

Tags: actionscript-2, webmethods

I have an issue when I try to send an EDI document to a partner using AS2 (HTTPS). The transaction is being translated correctly and when it reaches EDIINT step I got the error:

Invalid input - URIString     [EDIINT.000001.000003]

I already checked the URL provided by partner and it's working.
Something that is strange is that we can send the MDN when we receive any transaction from them, but when we try to send a transaction from our end, we got that error.

What's causing such errors and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

can you try encoding the URL string